# CQRS and Command, CommandHandler and Aggregate validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cqrs

I'm taking the first steps in implementing CQRS in a new project.
Following the CQRS approach, I'm using MediatR as the framework to orchestrate my commands.

I'm also using FluentValidation, and a ValidationBehavior, to implement command validation. But I'm struggling to define where to put which validation:

- In the command (using a CommandValidator with FluentValidation)
- In the command handler, as custom checks
- In the aggregate root (when calling operations directly on this aggregate)

I'd like to understand where to put which validation:

- Field validation (length, format, required, ...)
- Business rule validations that require an implementation of an IRepository (e.g. uniqueness based on a column, but not on a primary key)
- Business rule validations that do not require an implementation of an IRepository

As I currently have implemented it, I don't have access to **IRepository** implementations in my **aggregate** roots. It's the command handlers that get this repository injected by DI, and they execute operations on aggregate root, but are also responsible for calling e.g. Save or Add to finally update the database.

Comment: You're exactly on the right track in separating the 3 types of rules. Command vs command handler for field validation is opinion-based, but the question of using Repositories has to do with more fundamental concepts of DDD that have already been covered in detail on SO. You'll probably find the answer searching for "cross aggregate invariants". The specific question of uniqueness you'll find under "set validation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "ideal" CQRS your aggregate state should contain everything that is needed to execute commands, and you should not talk to other aggregates during command execution (because they are out of consistency boundaries)

So business rule validations (decision if you can execute a given command) should go to aggregate's command handler.

Command formatting rules (required fields, allowed values) should be checked before sending a command - on a client, and before passing a command to command handler (since we cannot fully trust a client).

Therefore I would keep command format validation rules somewhere closer to command definition - probably in the declarative form, not as a dedicated validator.

There are some cases where aggregate cannot fully check correctness of the command without querying state of other aggregates. Here is the [good article about inter-aggregate communication](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/11/22/4-secrets-inter-aggregate-communication-event-sourced-system/). In short - you should not talk to other aggregates during command execution.

The classic example is creating a user with unique name. Community consensus seems to be that:

- you validate user name to be unique in the client - before sending a command.
- User aggregate performs a command without check for uniqueness.
- Those rare cases where someone registered the same user name just before you send a command are caught in the projection code, and causes an exception that is resolved manually. Or there is some saga that would watch for duplicated user names and deal with this problems somehow.

So - business rule validation that require inter-aggregate communication better to be placed into Saga/Process Manager

Comment: If you validate the uniqueness of a user name in your command, wouldn't that mean that the command/controller requires a dependency on your specific repository, to check existence?

Comment: Yes, it would. But I'm saying you should not do any queries in the command handler. The main reason is that result of these queries is still inconsistent.